# how to connect cassandra db from exasol db with SSL option and multi node option

Tags: cassandra

I am completely new to `Cassandra DB` and want to connect `cassandra db` from exasol db using cassandra jdbc connection string with SSL option and multi node option.

I tried to connect but getting error:

> failed: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: please provide more information - what version of Cassandra, what version of the driver, what is the connection string, how SSL is setup on Cassandra side,  etc.

Comment: Cassandra Version 3.11.2, we use datastax core driver 3.7.2, connection string we use is 'jdbc:cassandra://Host1:port1/keyspace' USER <user name> IDENTIFIED BY <pwd> to connect cassandra from exasol, and for SSL is not validated (Trust all).

Comment: Cassandra 3.11.2 installs with Thrift disabled.  So if you're trying to connect via Thrift on port 9160, you'll need to enable that.  Also, doesn't Cassandra JDBC connect over CQL on 9042?  If that's available, you should use that instead.

Comment: I am using port 9142